# How to filter GitHub PRs with specific merge date?

Tags: github

I use the below filter to get PRs closed above 2017-03-19;  but, is there a way to filter with a specific date.

```
is:pr is:closed merged:>=2017-03-19 base:master sort:updated-desc
```

[image]

The below fails:

```
is:pr is:closed merged:=2017-03-19 base:master sort:updated-desc
```

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Yes, you can do so by filtering as follows:

```
is:pr is:closed merged:2017-03-19..2017-03-19 base:master sort:updated-desc
```

For more information concerning searching issues and pull requests in GitHub see [Searching issues documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-based-on-when-an-issue-or-pull-request-was-created-or-last-updated).

Comment: much useful for me :)

Comment: If someone adds a comment to a PR after it's merged, that still counts as being "updated." Small caveat in this method. I'm not sure what other actions change the updated time.

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO if someone adds a comment to a already merged PR, it's the intended behaviour that its updated date gets set to now. However the merged date is not affected by that. The filter provided in my answer filters based on merged date and uses updated only for sorting purposes.

Comment: Yes, the PR is still correctly filtered. However, it's no longer sorted by merge date because the last action was a comment and not the merge.

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO the result is sorted by `updated-desc`. Just change the sorting to `sort:merged-desc`

Comment: @rufer7 That sort does not work for me and is not mentioned in the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/sorting-search-results

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO you are right. The proposed sort is not working unfortunately. Sorry...